# Unable to click my wordpress dropdown menu submenu link

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

HI i'm unable to click my drop down menu's sub-menu link.I removed superfish.php and added a new super-fish.php file even though it is not working. The gap between parent link and child link is more when i was trying to click the child menu link it was disappearing. I tried to reduce the gap between parent and child in css but i was unable to do it please help me.
I think this not browser problem because i have tried in all browser no where it is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `top:4em` to `top:31px` seems to do the job.

```
li:hover ul, .sf-menu li.sfHover ul {
  left: 0;
  top: 31px;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

Comment: This is working but very sensitive. It top is 30px then it is working well one problem it is child menu is overlapping with parent. Is there any solution for this. Thanks in advance

Comment: I personally prefer that child overlaps the parent by atleast 1px so as to ensure that it doesn't hide when I move on to it. If this is not the problem, you have to provide a fiddle.

Comment: if you absolutely want a separation, I'd advise to add an `li` with `opacity:0` as first submenu item

Comment: see this is the site [link](http://socialpositives.com) where i have brought the code after small modifications it was not working.And sometimes it was showing as how it was showing in that linked site. What is the problem ?

Comment: It seems like you are using js for this, are you? And I see you are still using `top:em`

Comment: i have checked everything with firebug in both sites everything is same in both site then what is the problem and top:em is actual code when i copied from that code.One more interesting thing dropdown menu working showing correctly sometimes.

Comment: I am using chrome and I still see the gap and also I can see you still used em. Use pixels and update it. One thing I am not sure is that do you want the gap or not ?

Comment: I need gap and i want exactly how it is looking in this website[link](http://socialpostives.com). I'm sorry if i'm irritating you.

Comment: No problems buddy. Okay if you need gap then do you mind using an extra li with `opacity:0`. That way you won't need js at all

Comment: entire code of what? You go ahead create a fiddle and I'll change it

Comment: where i have to use li and opacity:0

Answer (score 0):

Change `top:4em` to `top:30px`

```
.sf-menu li:hover ul, .sf-menu li.sfHover ul {
left: 0;
top: 4em;
z-index: 99;
}
```

Relace it with

```
.sf-menu li:hover ul, .sf-menu li.sfHover ul {

left: 0;
top: 30px;
z-index: 99;

}
```

Comment: Thank for your reply it is working but the two parent and child are overlapping is there any other solution to overcome this